# tool to do statistics in the linux command line

Tags: linux

say I run a command that outputs space separated values over lines. Some of which are numbers. Is there a utility I can use to calculate the mean, median, standard deviation of these numbers? something like 'cut' but that outputs these statistics.

Comment: grep something? don't you miss either stdin or file as input?

Comment: also '*' is expanded by shell, you can reach limit when having too many files!

Comment: `awk` would be my choice for the basic functions, although the stddev function may be missing.

Comment: this is not about how to write the command. it is how to calculate statistics for the results

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789806/command-line-utility-to-print-statistics-of-numbers-in-linux || http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24934/command-line-tool-to-calculate-basic-statistics-for-stream-of-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out st: https://github.com/nferraz/st or sta (recommended): https://github.com/simonccarter/sta

From GitHub:

> sta
>
> Simple statistics from the command line interface (CLI), fast.
>   Description
>
> This is a lightweight, fast tool for calculating basic descriptive
>   statistics from the command line. Inspired by
>   https://github.com/nferraz/st, this project differs in that it is
>   written in C++, allowing for faster computation of statistics given
>   larger non-trivial data sets.
>
> Additions include the choice of biased vs unbiased estimators and the
>   option to use the compensated variant algorithm.
>
> Given a file of 1,000,000 ascending numbers, a simple test on a 2.5GHz
>   dual-core MacBook using Bash time showed sta takes less than a second
>   to complete, compared to 14 seconds using st.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider using [**clistats**](https://github.com/dpmcmlxxvi/clistats). It is a highly configurable command line interface tool to compute statistics for a stream of delimited input numbers.

#### I/O options

- Input data can be from a file, standard input, or a pipe
- Output can be written to a file, standard output, or a pipe
- Output uses headers that start with "#" to enable piping to gnuplot

#### Parsing options

- Signal, end-of-file, or blank line based detection to stop processing
- Comment and delimiter character can be set
- Columns can be filtered out from processing
- Rows can be filtered out from processing based on numeric constraint
- Rows can be filtered out from processing based on string constraint
- Initial header rows can be skipped
- Fixed number of rows can be processed
- Duplicate delimiters can be ignored
- Rows can be reshaped into columns
- Strictly enforce that only rows of the same size are processed
- A row containing column titles can be used to title output statistics

#### Statistics options

- Summary statistics (Count, Minimum, Mean, Maximum, Standard deviation)
- Covariance
- Correlation
- Least squares offset
- Least squares slope
- Histogram
- Raw data after filtering

NOTE: I'm the author.

Comment: If you recommended a product, you must disclose your affiliation with the product in your answers. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers

Comment: I've updated the post. However, it's not that hard to figure out I'm the author. I used the same account names so folks could figure it out. Clearly, you did.

Answer (score 1):

The R language would be perfect for this.  It runs in the terminal, its free and probably the most popular statistics languages out there.  So, it has tons of documentation on how to do neat things, including the ones you are asking for.

Comment: Can you add ab example?